Did Kurtis and Nick come back to Stack Overflow?
I'd love to hear Kurtis Beavers and Nick Craver are back on board, but I'm pretty sure they are still pretty happy at Microsoft. Why then do they appear as "Staff" (Kurtis) and "Mod" (Nick)?


By the way, the tag description for moderators still speaks of diamond moderators (with a diamond symbol...) I know what it means but it is probably confusing to new users!

Those labels indicate users that were staff or mods at the time of posting https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395384/indicator-on-meta-next-to-the-display-name-of-former-staff-and-or-mod-users-for

I complained about this at Introducing an accessibility dashboard and some upcoming changes to display links: "a recent update requires that users know the difference in meaning between a) blue and grey; b) orange and grey, thus failing [WCAG] 1.4.1 Use of Color".

@blackgreen I was a mod and developer, but my user doesn't show any labels for messages and posts I sent while in service. Also, Nick was not a Mod then, but a developer. So I'm not sure but this system is clearly broken IMO

@Sklivvz I don’t know the exact criteria for showing this label, but it might be a misconfiguration or outright a bug. You can reach out to staff via the Contact Us form and ask them to look into it.

Yeah, I think they're just using local user history records, @sklivvz - that works for some users, but it's sketchy - account history is slightly more accurate, but still busted for a lot of the first four years. Back in the day, we requested this feature several times and had it thrown back because fixing up the data would've been icky; I guess that ended up being true

@Shog9 I'm still missing a couple badges from skeptics because of this

@Karl: i put the bug tag for a reason. It's indeed a bug, or presumed so :-)

@Sklivvz the [bug] tag makes sense only after reading the comments. The post in and of itself doesn't read like a bug report that we can [status-review]. It only asks why two people have some label next to their usernames, and that is the question that got answers. You can re-ask a new question and frame it as an actual bug report, e.g. "why is there no former staff/mod label next to my username even if there should be one" and then we can mark it [status-review] to put it in staff's radar.

I honestly... don't care; I've reported the bug, do what you want with it. If you want edit the question so it makes sense to you, if at all useful.

Huh, neat observation. Practically the label is not identifying the user but the data. It's an edit done by staff and a comment made by a moderator. But because it is prominently displayed behind the user, it gets quite confusing and does not stand the test of time very well. I would consider that a bug, indeed. One that's going to stay exactly where it is.

No, Kurtis Beavers and Nick Craver didn't come back to Stack Overflow. That indicator means that they were a staff member/moderator at the time that they wrote they performed the action in question. It doesn't mean that they are one now.

Additionally, if you hover over the badge, you can see the tooltip saying that the user was a moderator at the time of this post activity.
